# Find all words/substrings that *don't* match regex?

Tags: python, regex

So I want to find all of the parts of the string that don't aren't in the regex.

Let's say I have a regex `r'foo|bar'` and string `'Hello foo how are you bar'`, how can I get every word other than what the regex matches so it returns `['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']`?

Comment: Is it always words that you need to exclude? If yes I would say regex is little overkill.

Comment: I'd probably start be trying to get a collection of all of the "words" (not always as easy as you think... what do you do with `well-respected`?) Then compare your list of words against the list of words you want to exclude.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a list comprehension and negate the regex match:

```
>>> st='Hello foo how are you bar'
>>> [w for w in st.split() if not re.search(r'foo|bar', w)]
['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

You did not ask, but you would likely want to use [anchors](https://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html) in your regex so that if you had `foofoo` or `barfoo` or `fooblulator` in the list it is handled as you expect.

And if you just have simple word look ups, not requiring a regex, the same method works:

```
>>> [w for w in st.split() if w not in {'foo', 'bar'}]
['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to @dawg's answer. But you can have negative look ahead in regex

```
st='Hello foo how are you bar'
[w for w in st.split() if re.search(r'^(?!(foo|bar))', w)] # ['Hello', 'how', 'are', 'you']
```

Answer (score 0):

This should do it:

```
\b(?!Foo\b|bar\b)[A-Za-z]+
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2nNs0v/1/)

We have:

```
\b         # match a word break
(?!        # begin a negative lookahead
  Foo\b    # match 'Foo' followed by a word break
  |        # or
  bar\b    # match 'bar' followed by a word break
)          # end negative lookahead
[A-Za-z]+  # match 1+ letters
```